# Можно ли подружить никак не связанные между собой шаблонные классы с помощью шаблонной дружественной функции?

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Существует два шаблонных класса, которые никак не связаны между собой и шаблонная функция. Необходимо сделать так что бы функция имела доступ к приватным полям и первого и второго класса. Если это невозможно, то объяснить почему?

Comment: Можно, делайте эту функцию дружественной для каждого из классов.

Comment: В дополнение к ответу @user7860670 прикреплю ссылку на хороший урок по дружественным функциям: https://ravesli.com/urok-126-druzhestvennye-funktsii-i-klassy/